# Combining $n$ lists

Tags: list-manipulation

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370848/pair-lists-to-create-tuples-in-order) question, I know how to combine two lists. In fact, if $X_1,X_2, X_3$ are lists with the same length, then the command `Transpose[X_1,X_2,X_3]` will work in a similar way, but for 3 entries. Now suppose I want to use $n$ lists  and want to use the transpose command for $n$. The value of $n$ is a parameter, so it can be changed, how do I work this?

To be concrete, below is a *pseudo-Mathematica* code of what I want to implement.

`n=10
 For[i=1, i<=n, i++{ X_i = RandomReal[{-1,1}, 25] }]
 X=Transpose[X_1,...,X_n]`

Each $X_i$ can be written as $X_i=[x_{i,1},\ldots,x_{i,25}]$, where each entry $x_{i,j}$ is random. Note that $X$ can be written as $X=\Big[ \{x_{1,1},x_{2,1}, \ldots,x_{n,1}\},\ldots, \{x_{1,25},x_{2,25},\ldots,x_{n,25}\} \Big]$, in words, $X$ is a list with 25 entries, each entry is another list with 10 numbers (because $n=10$ in this example) randomly generated.

The main problems is that I don't know how to create indexed lists and I don't know how to make this *general* transpose work.

Comment: `n = 10;
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, x[i] = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 25]];
Transpose[x /@ Range@n];`, but whay bother with such machinations when `RandomReal[{-1,1},{25,10}]` nets the same result?

Comment: There is a good reason for that, I wasn't aware of that command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be working very hard for what seems to be this:

```
Table[RandomReal[], {i,n}]
```

Comment: LOL - see commnent on OP, +1

Comment: Thank you for the help, looks like I have a lot learn!

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, there is a functionality in Mathematica if you want to apply a function to a variable number of arguments. This is actually the `Apply` or `@@` operation.
It works like:

```
f @@ {a,b,c}
(* f[a,b,c] *)
```

For example, if for any reason you need something along the lines of your Pseudo code; or you really have a variable number of lists containing real data to work with, you can try with `Join` for example:

```
X = {};
For[i = 1, i <= 25, i++, X = Append[X, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 25]]];
Join @@ X
```

In which case all 25 lists are passed as individual arguments to `Join`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the lists that you want and then use `Join[list1,list2,...]` to combine them.

Since each list will combine of $n$ elements, you can use the following lines to create them:

```
n=10;
list1=Table[RandomReal[],n]
list2=...
```